# XPath with PL/SQL variables

Tags: sql, xpath, plsql

As a bloody newbie when it comes to complex sql commands, I want to execute two XPath database queries where the second command uses the result of the first one:

```
declare
version VARCHAR2(256);
document VARCHAR2(256);
begin

select ID_VERSION into version from VERSIONTABLE where extract(VERSION_XML, '//p:contract[@id="contract-001"]', 'xmlns:p="http://www.foo.com/v1"').getClobVal() IS NOT NULL;
select ID_DOCUMENT into document from DOCUMENTTABLE where extract(DOCUMENT_XML, '//p:content[@ref='$version']', 'xmlns:p="http://www.foo.com/v1"').getClobVal() IS NOT NULL;

end;
/
```

The first command will always return exactly one `ID_VERSION`. As a result, I want to print `document`.

The question: how do I properly include `version` in the second command? Executing above commands, it outputs following error at the code position of `'$version'`:

```
PLS-00181: unsupported preprocessor directive '$VERSION' [SQL State=65000, DB Errorcode=6550]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The string concatenation operator in PL/SQL is `||` - so you'd want to do something like:

```
select ID_DOCUMENT
  into document
  from DOCUMENTTABLE
  where extract(DOCUMENT_XML,
                '//p:content[@ref=' || version || ']', 
                'xmlns:p="http://www.foo.com/v1"').getClobVal() IS NOT NULL;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked partly: the former error is gone of course, but for some reason it doesn't find any data: if I try `version := 'version-123;` `select ID_DOCUMENT into document from DOCUMENTTABLE where extract(DOCUMENT_XML, '//p:content[@ref=' || version || ']', 'xmlns:p="http://www.foo.com/v1"').getClobVal() IS NOT NULL;` the error is `ORA-01403: no data found`. However, there is data if I insert the string directly. Do you know the reason? Thanks in advance!